# Forward declaration in Objective-C in child class

Tags: objective-c, forward-declaration

In our project, we have a series of classes that used to work fine.
In Xcode 4.1's latest update the behaviour seems to have changed, highlighting an issue in our code that wasn't detected before.

Here's the situation, using example classes to narrow the problem down:

- Class **Child** inherits from class **Parent**
- Class **Parent** declares (.h) an **ElementalObject** *(but doesn't make it a property, because it's supposed to be protected, as in only used in **Parent** and its children)* where `@class ElementalObject` is used.
- Class **Parent** assigns the **ElementalObject** (imported with `#import`) in the .m
- Class **Child** calls a method on the **ElementalObject** through `[theElementalObject doStuff];`

An error is shown at this step:

```
**ARC semantic issue:**  
Receiver type 'ElementalObject' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

Since the Child class does not redeclare, or reassign, `theElementalObject`, I do not see why it should contain an import to the `ElementalObject` header file, which is already imported in the `Parent` implementation file.

It seems, unless I'm also misunderstanding that, that the compiler tells me otherwise.
Could anyone clear this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to import `ElementalObject.h` in the child class's `.m`.

While the child class is not declaring the property, nor assigning it, it is trying to call methods on it. Unless the header for `ElementalObject` is imported, it has no idea what methods `theElementalObject` responds to.

Basically, if you do *anything* with a class, you must import the `.h` somewhere for the `.m` that uses it.

Comment: I thought that was the point of Objective-C's "class dispatch" feature that it found the proper methods on the fly, but anyway, why did it stop working if I MUST have imported it? (I probably should have said in the question that importing the .h in the real class has solved the problem for me, but I'm still stumped on the explanation.)

Comment: How the runtime searches for implementations is a separate matter from validating method calls at compile-time. To my knowledge, importing class headers for classes that you call methods on has always been required, but I could be mistaken. As for why it broke now? Xcode updates often have a stricter compiler than the previous version and somehow your case was being missed. The header could have also been imported into the .m in another way.